# Javafx -netscape.javascript.JSException: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Vallasois'. Expected '}' to end a object literal

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I'm having hard time figuring whats going wrong with my codes, seem like there is a missing '}' in the string that i'm trying to parse. 
 So basicalluy what i'm trying to do is to execute javascript code with the aide of javafx api,

javascript function

```html
function fillWaypoints(location){
 ArrayWaypoints.push(location)
 
}
```

java codes to execute javascript

```
     @FXML
public void displayDirection(){
for(int i =0;i< lists.get(0).size() ;i++){
System.out.println("routes -->"+lists.get(0).get(i));
engine.executeScript("fillWaypoints("+lists.get(0).get(i)+")");   
}
```

The output of

```
lists.get(0).get(0) for example is
```

{location: Antoine Vallasois Ave, Vacoas-Phoenix, England, stopover:true}

Answer (score 0):

The javascript is (presumably) expecting an object literal, in JSON format. The string you are getting is not valid JSON. A valid JSON representation would be

```json
{"location": "Antoine Vallasois Ave, Vacoas-Phoenix, England", "stopover":true}
```

Or, if you intend the `location` to be an array,

```json
{"location": ["Antoine Vallasois Ave", "Vacoas-Phoenix", "England"], "stopover":true}
```

Comment: how do i need to put the string with "\"? i tried it it is not accepting

Comment: "{location:" + item.getCitizenAdress()+", stopover:true}"

Comment: above is my string

Comment: @NickyLarson That won't give either of the forms I posted in the answer. The keys must be quoted, as must any string values. It would probably be better to use a dedicated library to generate valid JSON, instead of trying to do it all by hand.